# Select element's change event function not executing

Tags: jquery, events

When I put the following code within the $(document).ready(function () {} it executes correctly.

```
                $('#welcome select').change(function () {
                var stateSelected = $('option:selected', this).val();

                setCookie('ia_state', stateSelected);

                switch (stateSelected) {
                    case 'Virginia':
                        window.location = '/Login/VA';
                        break;
                    case 'North Carolina':
                        window.location = '/Login/NC';
                        break;
                    case 'South Carolina':
                        window.location = '/Login/SC';
                        break;
                    default:
                        window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/pages/login/login.html';
                }
            });
```

However, I need to place this code elsewhere on the page in order to make it easily accessible by the user.

I have placed the code by the select element that the user will have access to like so:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


$('#welcome select').change(function () {
                var stateSelected = $('option:selected', this).val();

                setCookie('ia_state', stateSelected);

                switch (stateSelected) {
                    case 'Virginia':
                        window.location = '/Login/VA';
                        break;
                    case 'North Carolina':
                        window.location = '/Login/NC';
                        break;
                    case 'South Carolina':
                        window.location = '/Login/SC';
                        break;
                    default:
                        window.location = 'http://www.mysite.com/pages/login/login.html';
                }
            });




</script>
<div class="clear" id="welcome">
<p class="message">
    Welcome!</p>
<p class="switch-state">
    Switch State</p>
<select id="state-select" size="1"><option selected="selected" value="Virginia">VA</option><option value="North Carolina">NC</option><option value="South Carolina">SC</option><option value="Alabama">AL</option><option value="Alaska">AK</option><option value="Arizona">AZ</option><option value="Arkansas">AR</option><option value="California">CA</option><option value="Colorado">CO</option><option value="Connecticut">CT</option><option value="Delaware">DE</option><option value="Florida">FL</option><option value="Georgia">GA</option><option value="Hawaii">HI</option><option value="Idaho">ID</option><option value="Illinois">IL</option><option value="Indiana">IN</option><option value="Iowa">IA</option><option value="Kansas">KS</option><option value="Kentucky">KY</option><option value="Louisiana">LA</option><option value="Maine">ME</option><option value="Maryland">MD</option><option value="Massachusetts">MA</option><option value="Michigan">MI</option><option value="Minnesota">MN</option><option value="Mississippi">MS</option><option value="Missouri">MO</option><option value="Montana">MT</option><option value="Nebraska">NE</option><option value="Nevada">NV</option><option value="New Hampshire">NH</option><option value="New Jersey">NJ</option><option value="New Mexico">NM</option><option value="New York">NY</option><option value="North Dakota">ND</option><option value="Ohio">OH</option><option value="Oklahoma">OK</option><option value="Oregon">OR</option><option value="Pennsylvania">PA</option><option value="Rhode Island">RI</option><option value="South Dakota">SD</option><option value="Tennessee">TN</option><option value="Texas">TX</option><option value="Utah">UT</option><option value="Vermont">VT</option><option value="Washington">WA</option><option value="West Virginia">WV</option><option value="Wisconsin">WI</option><option value="Wyoming">WY</option><!-- 
                        <option value="North Carolina">NC</option>
                        <option selected="selected" value="Virginia">VA</option>
                     --></select></div>
```

However, this code does not run when value of the select element is changed on the page. What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit:

I have placed the javascript after the div element "welcome" and I also have it within a $(document).ready(function () {} function.

The function is now being hit the very first time the page loads. However, it is not being called when the value of the select element is changed. It is as if the event is not hooked up to the handler now.

Comment: Put it below your `select` element, but why does that code need to be accessible? It runs once, and is thereafter useless. **EDIT:** Nevermind. By *accessible*, I thought you were talking about variable scope.

Comment: What do you mean by the user having "access" to the script?  What "user" are you referring to there?

Comment: Instead of `$('option:selected', this).val();`, do `$(this).val();`.

Comment: This is all being put together within a CMS. The select element is editable by the user when he/she clicks the Source button within CK Editor. This allows the user to edit the contents of the select element. Additionally, the user must also be able to edit the urls from CK Editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the script **after** the "welcome" `<div>`, not before it.

Scripts are run when they're "seen" by the HTML parser.  Thus, your script runs before the "welcome" `<div>` is part of the DOM, so the selector comes up empty. If you put your script after it, however, it should work. (At least, the selector will find what it's looking for.)

Comment: I placed the script after the "welcome" div. It still is not running the function when the value is changed. I have a breakpoint set in Firebug and it is never being hit.

Comment: @Darren [Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8eNkW/) demonstrating that a "change" handler in a `<script>` block after an HTML pattern like yours works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be in a document ready function or after the content it is referencing. You can have more than one `$(document).ready(function() {});` in your page.

Comment: Odd, I placed it after the "welcome" div and I placed it inside a separate $(document).ready(function () {} and it is still not being called when I change the value of the select element.

Comment: @Darren But in your original question you said that it **does** work when it's in a "ready" handler.

Comment: You are right and I am sorry for the confusion. The "ready" handler that I was referring to is the one that is directly within the code behind file for the page. However, in order for me to make it accessible to the user I am trying to place it within a editable "block" within a CMS. When I place the code within another "ready" function in the block it is never being hit and I don't understand why. Sorry for the confusion.